# Docker Error: No such container: friendlyhello

Tags: docker

I'm trying to stop and remove a docker - container.

I started with docker turorial part1, now part2 from here: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app

I copied souce from there. and its also available here: https://gist.github.com/sl5net/8b510bc0d3e00c474575e010003406c1

Here you could see how my console looks like:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.431]
C:\fre\private\docker\test18-05-14_05-27>docker build -t friendlyhello .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

BTW solution: I swaped to linux container (right click>contextmenu on docker icon)

```
C:\fre\private\docker\test18-05-14_05-27>docker build -t friendlyhello .
... Successfully built itsdangerous MarkupSafe
Successfully tagged friendlyhello:latest

C:\fre\private\docker\test18-05-14_05-27>docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

C:\fre\private\docker\test18-05-14_05-27>docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED    SIZE
friendlyhello       latest              7d4d1e0f78e6        8 minutes ago    151MB
python              2.7-slim            46ba956c5967        9 days ago    140MB

C:\fre\private\docker\test18-05-14_05-27>docker container stop friendlyhello
Error response from daemon: No such container: friendlyhello

C:\fre\private\docker\test18-05-14_05-27>docker rm -f friendlyhello
Error: No such container: friendlyhello
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is no container available with the name `friendlyhello` as you are simply running the container using `docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello`, here `friendlyhello` is the name of the image, and not the container's name.

**Either** run that container by giving it a name like below:-

```
docker run -p 4000:80 --name SOMENAME friendlyhello
```

In this case you will be able to stop and remove that container using the below command

```
# container stop
docker container stop SOMENAME

# container removal
docker rm -f SOMENAME
```

**Or** if running without giving a name to the container, you will have to use the ***ID** of the container* in the commands to stop and remove, even in various other commands you will be using the ID to refer that con

Comment: I would replace `docker container stop SOMENAME` by `docker stop SOMENAME`

Comment: No such container: 7d4d1e0f78e6 But no error by using SOMENAME  But it also works if i use Hostname-ID (44d80922e721) from the welcome page of http://localhost:4001

Comment: can you `docker ps -a` again? the id will keep on changing

Comment: id must have changed to someother value

Comment: can the container be stopped using tag name if name is not provided to the container?

Comment: yes that can be done, by default docker generates a name and id for the container by itself, you can use any of them?

Comment: I hit this problem - for some reason the name I had explicitly assigned to the container failed, but using `docker ps -a` to find the new id to use to `rm` worked

Answer (score 27):

The tutorial shows:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED
1fa4ab2cf395        friendlyhello       "python app.py"     28 seconds ago
```

You haven't added a name (tag) to your container, so you must use its ID to stop it:

```
docker container stop 1fa4ab2cf395
```

`friendlyhello` is the name of the *image*, not the container.

See [`docker run --name`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#container-identification) to give it a name.

If you don't have a name, you will the ID with `docker ps -a`

The OP adds:

> using docker stop 8e008ebf3ad7 its out of list using: docker container ls buts stays in list using: docker ps -a

```
docker stop 8e008ebf3ad7
8e008ebf3ad7
docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
               NAMES
5227976cb9bb        friendlyhello       "python app.py"     About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:4001->80/tcp   SOMENAME

docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS
     PORTS                  NAMES
5227976cb9bb        friendlyhello       "python app.py"     About an hour ago   Up About an hour
     0.0.0.0:4001->80/tcp   SOMENAME
8e008ebf3ad7 friendlyhello "python app.py" 6 hours ago Exited (137) About an hour ago
```

That is expected: a stop will put a container in an "Exited" state, which is handy when you want to debug a container which stopped without your consent!

You can then do a `docker container rm <ID>` in order to reomve it from the `docker ps -a` list.

Note that if you had launch your container with `docker run --rm ...`, a stop would have stopped *and* removed (deleted) the container directly.

Comment: @kakabali no, it is *not* incorrect (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_stop/). Docker switched to a context-based syntax some time ago already. `docker stop` is the old syntax, kept for backward compatibility reason.

Comment: @kakabali See all the other `docker container xxx` commands here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container/

Comment: same error with ID: 
docker container stop 7d4d1e0f78e6 
Error response from daemon: No such container: 7d4d1e0f78e6

Comment: @SL5net What `docker ps -a` returns?

Comment: @kakabali 8e008ebf3ad7        friendlyhello       "python app.py"     5 hours ago
    Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:4000->80/tcp   eloquent_bhaskara

Comment: it is running with container id - 8e008ebf3ad7 now you should now use `docker stop container 8e008ebf3ad7 `

Comment: @kakabali yes its without errors by using the ID got from: docker ps -a

Comment: A group solution. Since the commentary by VonC "What docker ps -a" I was on the right track. And i already on tests.
And VonC was also correct with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323199/docker-error-no-such-container-friendlyhello/50323223?noredirect=1#comment87663741_50323223. The hint with the ID did not work if you follow the instructions (ls --all give a different ID).

Comment: using docker stop 8e008ebf3ad7
its out of list using: docker container ls
buts stays in list using: docker ps -a
https://gist.github.com/sl5net/20b3651e43fa55d9ad77901ce3f40241

Comment: And docker container rm will remove it if the list

Answer (score 0):

docker pull solr => to pull the docker image
docker run -p 8983:8983 -t solr => run the image and define the port
http://localhost:8983/ - run on local web browser